# Number input not following @media styling

Tags: html, css, input, media-queries

I have set up a page, where there are `@media` queries below to resize for mobile guests:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #survey-container {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 8px;
    }
    .input-field {
    width: 85px;
    }
    .input-select {
    width: 85px;
    }
  }
  @media all and (max-height: 800px) {
  #survey-container {
    min-height: 100%;
    }
  }
```

The `input-field` class is attached all `input` tags that have type `number`, `text`, or `email`, and the `input-select` is for a dropdown input. However, my input for Age does not follow the `@media` style for `input-field` as shown below:

[image: the result]

As can be seen, the field for Age is not the same size as the other fields, despite being styled by the same class, `input-field`.

Oddly, I can set the `width` of the fields to `75px`, and they will even out, but I do not want them to be `75px`. Also, by changing the `input-type` from `number` to `text`, they will both be `85px` in size, however the Age input must be a `number`, so that solution cannot be used.

Comment: Try targeting   input[type="number"] { width:85px; }

Comment: @Alex I was certain that would fix it, but no, it didn't even have any effect for some reason. Really weird.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework like bootstrap in your css?

Comment: @Alex No, not at all. The only tag in my `<head>` is a viewport.

Comment: [They're the same size when I try it](https://jsfiddle.net/vhskLj2w/).  Are you sure you don't have other CSS affecting these inputs?

Comment: I followed that link but cannot find your survey. Where is it?  (Questions are supposed to contain a [mcve] demonstrating the problem you're asking about; as it stands this is not reproducible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
#survey-container input[type="text"],
#survey-container input[type="email"],
#survey-container input[type="number"],
#survey-container input[type="select"]{
width: 85px;
}
```

Comment: can you please edit the question with your html and css for (not media)?